# How to solve error in windows phone 8 application when retrieving app from background with web services?

Tags: web-services, windows-phone-7, soap, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am developing application and facing a problem when I use web services.

At any page which request web service, if app goes to background (by search or menu press for example) before request complete it causes an error when I retrieve the application from background again:

> An error (Exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' was thrown.) occurred while transmitting data over the HTTP channel.

Any solution for this problem ?

Comment: I have same exception throwing in similar case, but my app is not crashing. I am getting this exception when Common language Runtime Exception is checked in the visual studio(Alt+Ctrl+E).

Comment: I am getting the exception and the app crashes. I have also tried with try and catch. @JagathMurali But you say it can be removed in the runtime exception?

Comment: @AhmedEmad Did you solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

When your application is sent to background, it is suspended, and all connections are therefore cut off. There's nothing you can do about that. Just catch the error and retry the call to the webservice.

Comment: +1, only one remark that if OP is downloading/uploading files (only) he can try to use BackgroundTransfers. In other cases, as you have said.

Comment: thanks for this solution but i already tried that and error can't be catched . i connect to SOAP services and each time i try to catch the error ir only crash at refrence file of the service which is created dynamicly by adding service refrence

Comment: You can manually edit the reference file to add in a trycatch block. You'll need to do it every time you regenerate the service reference

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the webservice again when the application is reactivated. One way of doing it is to maintain a bool variable flag.

- set it to true when the webservice is started.
- set it back to false when the response is received
- in the Application_Activated event handler(App.xaml.cs) check the status of flag and call the webservice again if the flag is true.

Otherwise if you just wish to keep your webservice running under lock screen then set

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.UserIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
```

Comment: I am struggeling with the same problem. But I am unsure what will happen with line of code you supplied and where it is put in a project. What will happen if the webservice answers during the application is deactivated, will it finish the function call? or what happens whit the function? Further is the line supposed to go in the app.xaml?

Comment: Not UserIdleDetectionMode but ApplicationIdleDetectionMode. [More information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff941090(v=vs.105).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If your app goes to background your webrequest wont complete, You cant do anything about that. **But you can prevent crash**.
When you know the app is going background ( may be in `onNavigatedFrom()`) **you detach the handler you previously attached to `xxCompleted` event**  or **handle the thrown exception in handler for `xxCompleted` in the same way**. The first solution implies you service client object must be a class member (private maybe), otherwise it wont be in scope in `onNavigatedFrom()`. To complete the request later you may use a marker ( `bool successful, required`) and in `OnNavigatedTo()` you can do like:

```
if(required && !successful)
{
    // make the request again
}
```

**still exception will be caught in the generated reference file, but the app wont crash and you'd know when you need to make the webrequest again.**

---

I found the same problem, when I tried to fetch a `sas` uri and calling the `PhotoChooserTask.show()` simultaniously. So I had to ensure that webrequest is complete before the calling `PhotoChooserTask.show()`.

Comment: i request service through Viewmodel not through view so can there be any other way to do that without handling issue in onNavigatedto?